# Is the OpenRasta Project Actively Developed

Tags: .net, rest, openrasta

What's up with OpenRasta is it dead project? If I go to http://openrasta.org/download.html and try to do the:

```
o add-wrap openrasta-full
```

I receive the following:

```
\# OpenWrap Shell 1.1.0.35
\# Copyright © naughtyProd Limited 2009-2011
\# Using ...\AppData\Local\openwrap\wraps\_cache\openwrap-1.0.0.63365789\bin-net35\OpenWrap.dll (1.0.0.0)
```

Project repository doesn't exist but -project has been specified.

I can try to download it from:

> https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki/Downloading-and-Compiling-OpenRasta

but there doesn't seem to be a version for .NET 4.0

On InfoQ there's a recording with Sebastien Lambla where he talks about OpenRasta 3... but where is it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your three questions:

1. OpenRasta 3 is just the branding for the 2.2 codebase i've been working on. A lot of it is indeed in the code-bunker, as there's a large backlog of changes that are in the process of being applied to the current version of all packages, as well as a lot of cleaning up to do (mainly, get the new site live, remove the openrasta-stable github project as well as the old svn code, migrate some code that never made it in the github transition back in git, etc etc). It's actively being worked on, just not as much in public as the existing codebase. You can see the code that's live at http://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-core, where there are many pending pull requests and more work being done. I'd say there is a lot of activity still :)
2. To install when using OpenWrap, you need an OpenWrap-enabled solution, so you'll have to follow the openwrap tutorial first. I'll release a package soon that enables just creating new openrasta sites from a command (that's part of the alpha OR3 code i've showcased a little bit), so you'll be able to do an `o add-wrap openrasta-devtools -sys` once and create your site with an `o create-orsite`, that ought to make the initial config much easier. Again it is being worked on.
3. There is no specific .net 4 build for OR 2.1, because you can happily run OpenRasta 2.0 and 2.1 in a .net 4 environment. .net 4 support (including dynamic and a few other niceties) will be for OR 3.0, but this is just *adding* features (such as a no-config option for the asp.net hosting) rather than needing a specific build to run. Have you encountered .net 4 specific issues you need help with?

I know there's been a lot of questioning about the future of OpenRasta, work is still ongoing, we have new contributors, it just takes a little more time than I'd have liked to get all the pieces running, but we'll get there, and we still have one of the strongest communities amongst alternative web frameworks, this will continue.

Comment: Great to hear that it's still alive and being worked on. I tried to compile the openrasta-stable version on github, using VS2010 and Windsor Castle 2.5.1, and ran into some problems, not related to .NET 4 though, but just wondering why there were no solution for VS2010... I'll have a try with the latest...

Comment: Just got the code at:
git://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-core.git
however it doesn't seem to contain any CastleWindsor integration code, so where do I get that from ? Seems like:
https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-castle-windsor.git
is empty....
Do I just replace the core in the stable version with the core in the latest version??

Comment: Some repositories are lagging a bit behind. The openrasta-castle-windsor packages are available on openwrap. I'll make sure all code is sync'd back in the next couple of days as I'm finishing maintenance of the repositories

Answer (score 1):

I am using open-rasta and it is working just fine. You need to clone the openrasta-core git repo.

git://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-core.git

This repo just got some updates a few days ago so I know Sebastien is still working hard.

I am not sure when OR version 3 is due, there is still some radio-chatter surrounding it so I suspect he is in the code-bunker with that.

I hope that helps

Jonny